# Python27: Class to create pyserial connection, handle Error

Tags: python-2.7, error-handling, pyserial

I am reading data from a sensor via pyserial. The Sensor is connected via USB which can be differ from time to time, that's the reason I implemented a method which finds the right usb port.

My example code:

```
class Sensor:
    'Class to implement a sensor'

    #constructor of Vaisala with default setup of the serial connection
    def __init__(self):
        self.port = Sensor.read_port(self)
        self.ser = serial.Serial(
            port = Sensor.read_port(self),
            baudrate =19200,
            parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
            stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
            bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,
            timeout = 2
            )


    #returns the port to which the sensor is connected
    def read_port(self):
          #method to determine port
```

This example works with my given sensor. My question now is how do I handle errors in this case.

For example, if there is no Sensor connected, the terminal will raise an SerialException because the method read_port() couldn't find a sensor. I tried to use in the read_port() a try case with exception but I wasn't successful at all. Could someone give me a hint how could I solve my problem?
I could also instead of using the constructor of the class, implementing another function called for example serial_connection(), which sets the port, baudrate and so on, but I think than I wouldn't need to use a class.

Thanks for any help!

Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no device the error will occur during the init. So:

```
class Sensor:
'Class to implement a sensor'

#constructor of Vaisala with default setup of the serial connection
def __init__(self):
    try:
        self.port = Sensor.read_port(self)
        self.ser = serial.Serial(
        port = Sensor.read_port(self),
        baudrate =19200,
        parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,
        timeout = 2)
    except SerialException:
        import os
        print "Error connecting"
        os.exit(0)


#returns the port to which the sensor is connected
def read_port(self):
      #method to determine port
```

Comment: Thx! I miss understood the error in my case, but your example is perfect right!